# how to create a function that takes a function as a parameter?

Tags: f#

This is just an experienting/learning example.  I'm an extreme functional noob.

F# code to be used from C#:

```
module C
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
let Log format (f:Action<List<Object>>) =
    let arguments = f.Invoke(new List<Object>())
    let message = String.Format(format, arguments)
    Console.Write(message)
```

C# code that calls it:

```
   C.Log("Hello {0}", c =>
       {
          c.Add("World");
       });
```

Expected Result

```
Hello World
```

Actual Result

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a new `List<Object>` and passing it to an `Action<T>`.  An `Action<T>` delegate doesn't return any values hence you never get this list back.  Instead the `Invoke` method just returns `null` which is ignored in the `String.Format` call.  You need to persist the list between the delegate invoke and `String.Format`

Try the following

```
let list = List<Object>();
f.Invoke(list);
let message = String.Format(format, list.ToArray());
```